# Geoserver 2.8 image mosaic reprojection non transparent artefacts

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic

I'm currently upgrading my companies instances of Geoserver from version 2.4 to 2.8 everything has worked fine for the vector layers. However when a request  is made for aerial imagery as an image mosaic layer, projected to EPSG:3857 is made we have non transparent artefacts where new data is created from the projection.

[image: Output displayed in QGIS]

The files making up the mosaic are RGB tiffs with a white background.

Now as far as I can tell all the settings are the same as the 2.4 instance, the settings for 2.8 are

[image: Geoserver settings]

So far I haven't been able to find a solution to the problem and have found myself going round in circles. I hoping some else has come across this issue whether as a configuration mistake or a bug with 2.8.

Comment: Can you remove the OutputTransparentColor setting?

If that does not help I would suggest to open a jira and provide 2 sample tiff files so that we can replicate the eventual issue.

Comment: @simogeo I removed th OutputTransparencyColor setting, and it removed all transparency. Have played around with different versions and the functionality changed after version 2.5.5.1.  I'll raise an issue and thanks for your help